# How to output a table in Matlab by altering the function statement?

Tags: matlab, output

My technique of making a vector out of "column" variables in a table only works part of the time. What is different about K1 from index in the following code? I am debugging a numerical method and I need the columns index, X, K1, K2, K, Y. All works fine until I add K1, K2, and K? How to do?

MM

What is needed is to properly initalize K1, k1, K2, k2, K, and k.
Corrected code is below.

FUNCTION CODE:

```
function [index,X,K1,K2,K,Y] = impeulerT(x,y,x1,n)
% modified version of Improved Euler method found in
% Elementary Differential Equations by Edwards and Penney 
X=x;               % initial x
Y=y;               % initial y
x1 = x1;           % final x
n = n;             % number of subintervals
h = (x1-x)/n;      % step size
index = 0;         % initialize index
k1=0; K1=k1;       % initialize k1
k2=0; K2=k2;       % initialize k2
k=0; K=k;          % initialize k
for i=1:n;         % begin loop
k1=f(x,y);         % first slope
k2=f(x+h,y+h*k1);  % second slope
k=(k1+k2)/2;       % average slope
x=x+h;             % new x
y=y+h*k;           % new y
X=[X;x];           % update x-column       
Y=[Y;y];           % update y-column
index = [index;i]; % update index-column
K1=[K1;k1];        % update K1 column
K2=[K2;k2];        % update K2 column
K= [K;k];          % update K column
end                % end loop
ImprovedEulerTable=table(index,X,K1,K2,K,Y)
clear
end
```

CALL CODE:

```
[index,X,K1,K2,K,Y] = impeulerT(0,1,1,10);
```

LOG:

```
Output argument "index" (and maybe others) not
assigned during call to "impeulerT".
```

Comment: Please don’t edit the answer into your question, it invalidates the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are clearing your variables before you can return them. The error you receive can be explained [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97825-why-do-i-get-the-error-output-argument-variable-and-maybe-others-not-assigned-during-call-t).

To fix your code, just simply remove or comment the clear statement after you create your table:

```
function [index,X,K1,K2,K,Y] = impeulerT(x,y,x1,n)
% modified version of Improved Euler method found in
% Elementary Differential Equations by Edwards and Penney 
    X=x;               % initial x
    Y=y;               % initial y
    x1 = x1;           % final x
    n = n;             % number of subintervals
    h = (x1-x)/n;      % step size
    index = 0;         % initialize index
    k1=0; K1=k1;       % initialize k1
    k2=0; K2=k2;       % initialize k2
    k=0; K=k;          % initialize k
    for i=1:n;         % begin loop
        k1=(x/y);         % first slope
        k2=(x+h)/(y+h*k1);  % second slope
        k=(k1+k2)/2;       % average slope
        x=x+h;             % new x
        y=y+h*k;           % new y
        X=[X;x];           % update x-column       
        Y=[Y;y];           % update y-column
        index = [index;i]; % update index-column
        K1=[K1;k1];        % update K1 column
        K2=[K2;k2];        % update K2 column
        K= [K;k];          % update K column
    end                % end loop
    ImprovedEulerTable=table(index,X,K1,K2,K,Y);
end
```

In general, you don't have to worry about clearing your variables inside a called function, since those variables only stay within that function's workspace. The only variables that change are the ones that are returned. Read more [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html) on how functions work with workspaces.

Comment: Thanks. The clear had been taken out but I see it somehow got put back into the code.  MM

Comment: You may want to leave the clear statement in the original question, for context for anyone else who may have this problem in the future.